# trying to use select statement for nested table

Tags: oracle

I have created a procedure which is working

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INIT_ACTOR_QUOTES AS 
 CURSOR Actor1 IS
 SELECT actorID FROM Actor;
 BEGIN
 FOR row IN FirstProcedure LOOP
 INSERT INTO ACTOR_QUOTES VALUES (row.actorID, AQ_NT(ACTOR_QUOTE_TYPE('',NULL, '', '')));
 DELETE TABLE (SELECT QUOTES FROM ACTOR_QUOTES WHERE ACTORID=row.actorID);
 END LOOP;
 END INIT_ACTOR_QUOTES;
 /
```

I am having trouble trying to Select from table QUOTES for any ACTORID variable for ACTORID on the ACTOR_QUOTES table.

The code I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM ACTOR_QUOTES WHERE ACTORID = ('200');
```

Help needed.

Comment: `DELETE TABLE` is not a valid command in PL/SQL (or SQL, for that matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT actorID, quotes.*
FROM ACTOR_QUOTES
CROSS JOIN TABLE(QUOTES) quotes
WHERE ACTORID = ('200');
```